# Disable Anchor Within Hover Div on Mobile Until Open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I've searched high and low but can't find a solution to this exact problem.

On a desktop browser, when the user hovers over an image, a div appears and they can click the link within the div if they want. However, on a mobile device, the hover is triggered by a click. If the user clicks in just the right spot, even though the div isn't visible yet, they can accidentally click the anchor and navigate away from the page. (In other words, the div goes from `display:none` to `display:block` at the same time that the link is clicked.)

I want to prevent that accidental click from happening on mobile browsers, however I still want the link to be usable once the div is visible.

My code:

```
<style>
  .staffpic {
    position: relative;
    width: 33.33333%;
    height: auto;
  }
  .staffpic:hover .popup {
      display: block;
  }
  .staffpic img {
      display: block;
      width: 110px;
      height: 110px;
      margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .popup {
      display:none;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: -5px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 15px;
      background-color: rgba(255, 153, 0, 0.9);
      color: #fff;
      text-transform: uppercase;
  }
</style>

<div class="staffpic">
  <img src="/wp-content/uploads/image.jpg" />
  <div class="popup">
    John Smith, Director<br/>
    CityName | <a href="mailto:johnsmith@example.com">Email John</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas? HTML, CSS, JS and jQuery solutions are all welcome! (Maybe something more clever than what I can think of using `pointer-events:none` along with some jQuery?)

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually about to encounter the same problem in a project, and jotted down a potential solution. Haven't tested it yet but it might help you out. The link should only trigger if the element has a display that's not 'none':

```
var popup = $('.popup'),
    display = popup.css('display');

if (!(display === 'none')) {
  popup.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

Comment: That didn't work for me, unfortunately. The moment the user clicks, the element's display is no longer "none," so it's not caught by the if statement. Maybe it needs some sort of duration set on it so that .2s after the element's style has changed, the link becomes clickable (or something like that). No idea how to do that though tbh.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but it's not elegant. I wanted to post it in case someone has this problem in the future and just needs something that will work!

I added a fake link in a span with the real link then set new display styles for it and the real link based on the parent span is being hovered over.

```
<style>
  .staffpic {
    position: relative;
    width: 33.33333%;
    height: auto;
  }
  .staffpic:hover .popup {
      display: block;
  }
  .staffpic img {
      display: block;
      width: 110px;
      height: 110px;
      margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .staffpic a { 
      display: none; /* Added */
  }
  .staffpic.link:hover a {
      display: inline; /* Added */
  }
  .staffpic.link:hover .fakelink {
      display: none; /* Added */
  }
  .popup {
      display:none;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: -5px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 15px;
      background-color: rgba(255, 153, 0, 0.9);
      color: #fff;
      text-transform: uppercase;
  }
</style>

<div class="staffpic">
  <img src="/wp-content/uploads/image.jpg" />
  <div class="popup">
    John Smith, Director<br/>
    CityName | <span class="link"><a href="mailto:johnsmith@example.com">Email John</a><span class="fakelink">Email John</span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd still love a cleaner solution without all this added html if someone has it.